# Why on Debug some field are "missing"?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, youtube-api

If I wrote:

```
IList<Video> videoContainer = videos.ToList();
DateTime theData = videoContainer.First().YouTubeEntry.Published;
```

the code works perfectly. 
But if I go in Debug mode and I analyze videoContainer expanding the fields, I can't see that field `Published`.

Why?

Comment: if fields are not published, it would have a small refresh link with it which you can click and try to populate the list.

Comment: What type exactly is a `Video` class?

Comment: uhm, but where can I find that "refresh" link? It is not on parent node :O

Comment: @JohnWillemse: it's Google.YouTube.Video

Comment: When `YouTubeEntry` is `dynamic` then it makes sense. Can you see other fields/properties? Is there a `Base Type` ?

Comment: Maybe `Published` is a field of the `YouTubeEntry`'s base type?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: yes I can see many field/properties, but not everythings. And I see a `base.` class, but the values are not stored. Doing .ToList() should populate them, but it doesnt. How can I do?

Comment: I see that field now: its on base.Member not publics.e.Published : but with QuickView Can't find them :O

Comment: `Published` is member of `AtomEntry` which is inherited by `AbstractEntry`, which is inherited by `YouTubeBaseEntry`, which is finally inherited by `YouTubeEntry`.

Comment: @JohnWillemse: why those fields are not showed in QuickView? I need to search for a value, understanding (in fact) the location where that value is stored, beucase I can't find it in the object structure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works a lot easier when you grab the item of interest first

```
IList<Video> videoContainer = videos.ToList();
var entry = videoContainer.First().YouTubeEntry;  // debug 'entry'
DateTime theData = entry.Published;
```

Comment: I can't do it, because "I don't know which field I need to use" :) I can't understand where that information it is stored on the object, but I know the value of the information. So I'm doing the reverse processing: find the field/structure by the field, but I can't :( Any suggestions?

Comment: Are we still talking about debugging?

Comment: Yes... with debug I should be able to find which field is having the value...dunno why if on QuickWiew I don't can browse base methods...

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick guessing, maybe you have some problem with build configuration setting. You can see the current setting at Visual studio menu: Build->Configuration Manager.

Just to make sure, do Build->Batch Build before doing the test. If you are using ASP.Net, make sure that the web (virtual folder in IIS, and site link) you use already refer to the latest code. It is just to make sure that your tested items will be the latest.